# Gimp Clone Tool Glitch

Tags: gimp, glitch

I guess I'm getting a glitch in the newest version of gimp, when I'm trying to use the clone tool it's not just working fine, it's not cloning at all its just draw other things

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have set the alignment to "fixed" shown circled in green below. Are you sure that's what you want?  Also you have set the clone to source to a pattern. Are you sure you want this?

[image]

Perhaps try using the alignment setting "none" or one of the other options.  If you set it to "fixed" the clone source is reset to the same point for each step of the brush stroke, which will result in that weird pattern.

Here's an example with the alignment set to "none".  Is this closer to what you were expecting?

[image]

If you don't want to clone from a pattern - set it to "image" as the source. Then CTRL+click on the image to set the target point for the source, then you can clone from the image.

[image]

For a more detailed description of the tool, be sure to check out the documentation in the GIMP user manual here: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-clone.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes now I found out that wasn't what I wanted instead of pattern I should've pick image

Answer (score 0):

You are so close to finding the answer yourself.

To the right of the red ring in your screenshot, there is the possibility to choose *Image* as *Source* instead of *Pattern*.

Click the tiny down arrow next to the word *Pattern* and choose *Image* instead.

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer so it can benefit others (and I can get points :-)).